# Código que cuando el usuario ingrese una frase, el programa ponga una palabra al revés la otra mayúscula, y así intercalado

Tags: python

Estoy escribiendo un código que cuando el usuario ingrese una frase, el programa ponga una palabra al revés, la siguiente en mayúscula y así sucesivamente pero al hacerlo el código me bota error y me dice `'function' object is not subscriptable`. ¿Qué podría hacer?

```
    frase=input("Ingrese una frase: ")
    lista=frase.split()
    for i in range(len(lista)):
       c1=c[::-1]
       lista[0]=c1

    print(lista)
```

Comment: El código que publicas no produce error. Tiene otros errores, pero no el que mencionas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En el ciclo `for` estas asignado una variable `c` que no existe.

```
for i in range(len(lista)):
   c1=c[::-1]
   lista[0]=c1
```

También estás asignado el valor modificado `c1` siempre al primer elemento de la lista, dejando los otros sin tocar.

Para dar vuelta cada palabra, basta con

```
for i in range(len(lista)):
    lista[i] = lista[i][::-1]
```

Aquí acceso cada elemento de la lista con `lista[i]`. Ese elemento es una cadena, por lo que puedo extraer una rebanada que lo invierta, con `lista[i][::-1].

Ahora la parte de que los elementos tienen que salir invertidos, en mayúsculas, invertidos, y así sucesivamente.

Para eso definimos una variable lógica `invertido` que nos dice si debemos invertir (`True`) o poner en mayúsculas la palabra (`False`). Dentro del ciclo vamos cambiando el valor a su opuesto en cada pasada.

```
frase = input("Ingrese una frase: ")
lista = frase.split()

invertir = True
for i in range(len(lista)):
    if invertir:
        lista[i] = lista[i][::-1]
    else:
        lista[i] = lista[i].upper()
    invertir = not invertir

print(lista)
```

**Ejemplo**

```
Ingrese una frase: la mona jacinta se ha puesto una cinta
['al', 'MONA', 'atnicaj', 'SE', 'ah', 'PUESTO', 'anu', 'CINTA']
```

Comment: ¡Muchas gracias!